# What is the correct design pattern to load dynamic/sequential views/controllers for iOS?

Tags: ios, segue

I have some logic that on app launch, downloads a few sequential screens that should be displayed at the checkout process.  The problem i'm having is that the ViewControllers can be re-ordered for different users.  I'm not sure how to have one controller call another controller.  Should all these steps be done with prepareForSegue in each controller?

For example I have my root controller A, it makes a web service call and returns 3 screens to display in a specific order: B, C, D

However, other users may get only screens D,C in that order.  The screens/controllers already exist in the app and are coded, I am just trying to figure out the best way to call them in various orders?

Comment: This question is too vague. You need to explain in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is a "screen"?  ViewControllers can display other view controllers in a [variety](http://goo.gl/kHxOoB) [of](http://goo.gl/KvrNtR) [ways](http://goo.gl/dT22kQ).  It may be the case that you should consider doing it programmatically instead of using segues.

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar.  An example usually helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you need to show view controllers dynamically and in different sequences to different users.

1. I would suggest you to not to use segues and show viewcontrollers **programmatically**. This will give you flexibility. For example, in iPhone you might have to push new viewcontroller and in iPad you might have to show it as a pop-up.
2. I would suggest you to look into **command design pattern**. This way after parsing your service response you call create commands to show you view controllers, keep them in queue (Invoker) and then execute the commands to show the viewcontrollers to users. Here, you do not need a full blown command pattern. You just need to maintain a queue and keep a context. You can also *consider having pre and post show (viewcontroller) methods*. This will help you in extending the code. You do not need to have them (pre/post) right-away but can plan your design accordingly. *For pre/post methods you can look into* **template design pattern**. Again, you will not need a full blown template.

Comment: Thanks. In terms of iOS, would you push all your controllers into a NavController and then use those accordingly?  I'm not sure how to actually implement what you are suggesting.

Comment: I will not push them on navigation controller statically but I will do it programmatically. [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewCotroller animated:YES]; This actually is a command, as mentioned earlier.